# Xamarin.Forms (IOS) build list view items dynamically (ObservableCollection and Task.Factory)

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, listview, xamarin.forms

Directly to the point.
My list view looks like the following xaml (Not 100% the same but should be detailed enough)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Result}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
                          HasUnevenRows="True">My content...</ListView>
```

This is bound to my view model which looks like this

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = null
private CancellationToken ct = CancellationToken.None
private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>()
public ObservableCollection<T> Source = new ObservableCollection<T>()
public ObservableCollection<T> Result = new ObservableCollection<T>()
public string Query
```

It also have the following method. This method is where my problem is. The method should behave like this:

- Get all elements from source (doesn't matter from where)
- Start a task which will run in the background (to build the list step by step, to reduce the number of at the same generated listview items, performance)

  - So it will add the elements to the result step by step (In my case 100 elements max at the same time)

And here is the code
Note: Source has been successfully loaded and the elements are in there

```
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.Clear();
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ct = cts.Token;
            Result.Clear();
            // Create background task
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var validItems = Source.Where(c => ((ISearchQueryViewModel)c).SearchData.RegexContains(Query)).OrderByDescending(c => ((ISearchQueryViewModel)c).Aktive).ToList();
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                var numberOfValidItemsToAdd = validItems.Count;
                var currentIndex = 0;
                while (numberOfValidItemsToAdd > 0)
                {
                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    var numberOfIndexes = 100;
                    if (numberOfValidItemsToAdd < 100)
                        numberOfIndexes = numberOfValidItemsToAdd;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIndexes; i++)
                    {
                        currentIndex++;
                        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                            return;
                        Result.Add(validItems[i]);
                    }
                    numberOfValidItemsToAdd -= numberOfIndexes;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                            return;
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                }
            }, ct));
```

This result the error

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Native stack trace:   0
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104da12b
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 171   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011dda6f41 objc_exception_throw + 48    2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001104df2f2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98    3
>   Foundation                          0x0000000111109d69
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193     4
>   UIKit                               0x0000000114652209 -[UITableView
>   _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 19416   5   UIKit                               0x000000011466d075 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 75   6
>   MobileClient.iOS 0x000000010fdfd9f9
>   xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217    7   ???
>   0x000000013f12d452 0x0 + 5353165906

Comment: I think you are hitting bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59896 - even though the titel of the bug is very specific, it seems more scenario's trigger it, reading the comments.

Comment: @Depechie thanks, It resolved the error. (Little workaround) I posted it as answer, hope you are okey with this c: Grateful thanks and have a nice day c:

Comment: @Depechie well^^ after a few tests, the same error came^^ If you know a good work around it would be great c: thank you and have a nice day c:

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. You have to set these 2 flags to false, clear the list it is bound to, turn the flags to true and then rebuild the list with new content.

```
                ListView.HasUnevenRows = false;
                ListView.IsGroupingEnabled = false;

                BindableGroupedObservableCollection.Clear();

                ListView.HasUnevenRows = true;
                ListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;

                BindableGroupedObservableCollection.Rebuild();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This answer is outdated, I will keep you ongoing if I found a
>   good way to resolve this problem.

Great thanks to @Depechie,

It was exactly this bug. I resolved it like this:

```
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
ct = cts.Token;
//Result.Clear(); <-- I only changed this to
//Result = new ObservableCollection<T>(); // <-- this
// Outdated, currently using Result.RemoveAt(0); <-- See code edit
```

Hope the bug will be fixed in the next version of Xamarin.Forms.

And Note: I created a new list because of performance issues. It would take a rather long time to manually remove item by item.

This was the answer that gave me that idea from the link below

```
while(myCollection.Count > 0) 
      myCollection.RemoveAt(0);
```

Link: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59896

The code above (in the question sould work like this after the next few updates^^ hopefully)

Thanks again and have a nice day c:

***Edit:***

I also could get rid of this wired looking method, so my code looks now exactly like this:

```
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.Clear();
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ct = cts.Token;
            // Result.Clear();
            // Workaround see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491781/xamarin-forms-ios-build-list-view-items-dynamically-observablecollection-and/48505622#48505622
            // Bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59896
            // Result = new ObservableCollection<T>();
            while (Result.Count > 0) // <-- Temporary fix, low performance on > 10000 elements and may result the same error
                Result.RemoveAt(0);
            // Create background task
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var validItems = Source.Where(c => ((ISearchQueryViewModel)c).SearchData.RegexContains(Query)).OrderByDescending(c => ((ISearchQueryViewModel)c).Aktive).ToList();
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                for (int i = 0; i < validItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    Result.Add(validItems[i]);
                    Thread.Sleep(25);
                }
            }, ct));
```

***Edit 2:***

Status update: Well the workaround doesn't work every time, i will keep you on going if I found a possible way to solve the problem. The code above will be kept actual right away.

***Edit 3:***

Currently investigating the System.Collection namespace. If someone is intrested this is the officially code from the collection namespace from ms

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,281923b8611114ec

Comment: I had the same error the thing that worked for me as temp work around is using a range observable collection and add all items in one go. The actual problem is because of the fact the UI tries to update to fast, to often ( My opinion )

Comment: So this one : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableRangeCollection.cs

Comment: @Depechie thank you really much, but I sadly can't change all collections :c and also my temporary solution crashes sometimes (only with a few objects), could you maybe give an example how you solved it? c: thanks

Comment: Sorry it’s not only... like I said I only switched out the regular observable collection to the range one and added a list with the add range method

Comment: @Depechie oh I'm sorry, I interpreted somehow something^^ but well, then I will search more after a fix c: but thank you anyway c:

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone runs into this like I did, I'll post my solution. If you are trying to use .Clear() use this:

```
while(MyObserableCollection.Count > 0)
{
    MyObserableCollection.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

If you are trying to use .Add() this will also cause an NS exception. I did this:

```
MyObservableCollection.Insert(MyObservableCollection.Count, myNewObject);
```

Both the .Insert() and .Remove() methods work so this was my workaround. If anyone else finds more info on this please comment on this post.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

in iOS it throws MonoTouchException exception when we work with ObservableCollection with Clear() and Add() functions of ObservableCollection.
The workaround for this is,

After

> Clear()

method invocation of ObservableCollection.

ReInitialise the Collection,

```
Result = new ObservableCollection<T>(GetNewList());
```